# Delete facebook cookie from liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

In my `liferay` application, I have a cookie from `.facebook.com` domain.

e.g. `sb 9kvzXbDiRD5sA8Oy2IQzkrMB`

Can I remove them from the `liferay` config?

I've tried to find a solution, no success yet.

Comment: You cannot manage others domain cookies

Comment: Cookies are pieces of data sent to and stored by browsers. A Liferay Portal can not send a cookie on behalf of other domain. It also does not receive cookies as it's not a user-agent (browser). There are no cookies in Liferay Portal's configuration. 

With respect to all of the above, your question does not make much sense. If you still think it's a valid question please update it and describe both the usecase and the problem in details.